# Is Selenium 2.52.0 Compatible With Firefox 51.0.1?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm writing program in Java and I need to record user interaction through browser. I use Selenium 2.52.0 and I plan to use Browsermob in order to record HTTP request.

Here is a simple code to run Selenium

```
public static void main(String...args) {    
    WebDriver driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://localhost/stres.php");
    String appTitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Application title is :: "+appTitle);
    driver.quit();
}
```

The Firefox browser run, but it didn't go to the specified address and only showed a blank white page. Then I got the following error

```
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    ... 7 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 52.803s
Finished at: Sun Feb 12 17:41:42 ICT 2017
Final Memory: 7M/153M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject1: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Is Selenium Webdriver 2.52.0 compatible with Firefox 51.0.1? If not, what version of Firefox work with Selenium 2.52.0?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No it is not compatible, use firefox 46 or older.

This is because Firefox started using [gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko) from firefox 47 and selenium needs a driver to work with it. So from Firefox 47 and over you need to have the geckodriver. You can get it from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Also You need to be using selenium 3.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

To launch latest version of Firefox Browser using Selnium, we need to set a system property “webdriver.gecko.driver” to the path of executable file “geckodriver.exe”

[Check this post.](http://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/launching-firefox-using-gecko-driver/)

Comment: I have tried using `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\myusername\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\mavenproject1\\geckodriver.exe");`, but I still got the same error without using System.setProperty

Answer (score 0):

It is compatible, but we need to add the gecko driver like we are adding for chrome driver and we need to set the path for it.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path where the driver is present");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");
```